# mongodb aggregate $sort by field value closest to some value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I want to sort following aggregated output using **aggregation $sort price value closest to 92**
Aggregation that I have used until

```
db.units.aggregate([
{$match: {category: 'a'}},
{$limit: 3},
{$project: {price:1, name: 1, category: 1}}
]);
```

Output

```
[{'_id': '111', 'price': 100, 'name': 'abc', 'category': 'a'}
{'_id': '222', 'price': 90, 'name': 'efg', 'category': 'a'}
{'_id': '333', 'price': 80, 'name': 'xyz', 'category': 'a'}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{'_id': '222', 'price': 90, 'name': 'efg', 'category': 'a'}
{'_id': '111', 'price': 100, 'name': 'abc', 'category': 'a'}
{'_id': '333', 'price': 80, 'name': 'xyz', 'category': 'a'}]
```

**Note:** Price field is nested object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting question. Well, this is how I would have done it

```
db.units.aggregate([

{$match: {category: 'a'}},

{$project: {diff: {$abs: {$subtract: [92, '$price']}}, doc: '$$ROOT'}},

{$project :{"diff" : 0}},

{$sort: {diff: 1}}

])
```

Now, what happening here is, I am taking the absolute difference of `price` values with the mentioned/specified value. and this way you can sort by that difference. And yeah.. You can even exclude that property from document using `{$project :{"diff" : 0}}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the absolute value of `92 - '$price'` to get this result:

the query is

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "price": "$price",
        "name": "$name",
        "category": "$category",
        "diff": {
            "$abs": {
                "$subtract": ["$price", 92]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "diff": 1
    }
}])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "222",
    "category": "a",
    "diff": 2,
    "name": "efg",
    "price": 90
  },
  {
    "_id": "111",
    "category": "a",
    "diff": 8,
    "name": "abc",
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "_id": "333",
    "category": "a",
    "diff": 12,
    "name": "xyz",
    "price": 80
  }
]
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/vfAwWMPCDbl](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vfAwWMPCDbl)

Comment: how it is different than the first answer ?

Comment: @UsmanRana it's the same idea, didn't saw you already posted this solution

Comment: chill. that's ok :)